# Specify numeric formats in the infix command

Tags: import, stata, infix-notation

I want to import a delimited text file into Stata. Some of the fields are numeric where the numbers are formatted with commas ( i.e 2,144.20). When I specify a numeric data type in the `infix` command for these columns, the values will be imputed to  missing.

```
infix 2 first str id 2-15 double amount 16-25 using "{datasetname}"
```

Is there a way to specify the numeric format (e.g `%20.2fc`) so that Stata does not treat them as non-numeric? Another way is to import it as string and convert it to numeric later. But I want to see if there is a way to specify the format in the `infix` command itself.

Comment: `infix` is a command, not a function. The spelling Stata (not STATA) has been standard for over 30 years. Edited accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such syntax. It would not even make sense from a Stata point of view as a format such as `%20.2fc` is a display format and controls what is shown (output), not what is read in (input).

Use `destring, ignore(",") replace` to fix such variables after reading them in.